# VBA Scraping Tables in JS

Tags: javascript, vba, web-scraping, html-table

i tried to gather every possible solution to get my code working, but unfortunately I am stuck.

I want to scrape the values from two different graphs, which are generated from JavaScript in the background.

https://us.soccerway.com/matches/2019/12/14/england/premier-league/liverpool-fc/watford-football-club/3029238/

The section I am interested is actually the two graphs in the middle of the page. 
"The general game stats chart" and the chart pie to the right.

the html code is presented below:

```
       <div class="block  clearfix block_match_stats_plus_chart-wrapper" id="page_match_1_block_match_stats_plus_chart_15-wrapper">

  <h2>General Game Stats Chart</h2>


  <div class="content  ">
    <div class="block_match_stats_plus_chart real-content clearfix " id="page_match_1_block_match_stats_plus_chart_15">
      <iframe src='/charts/statsplus/3029238/' style='width: 550px; height: 300px; overflow-y: hidden;' frameborder='no' allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no"> </iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

  (function() {
    var block = new Block('page_match_1_block_match_stats_plus_chart_15', 'block_match_stats_plus_chart', null);


    TimestampFormatter.format('page_match_1_block_match_stats_plus_chart_15');
  })();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the "Match" page while the charts actually loaded from an iFrame
This is the source you should be looking at:  https://us.soccerway.com/charts/statsplus/3029238/

**And this is the JavaScript function you should **scrape** the data from**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

window.addEvent('domready', function() {

    var chart = new PieChart('Possession');
         chart.addSeries('Possession', [{"name":"Watford FC","y":39},{"name":"Liverpool FC","y":61,"sliced":true}]);

    chart.highChartsOptions.plotOptions.pie.topmargin = '20';
    chart.highChartsOptions.plotOptions.pie.size = "80%";
    chart.highChartsOptions.plotOptions.pie.center = ['50%', '55%'];

    chart.render('page_chart_1_chart_statsplus_1_chart_possession_1-wrapper');

});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Sammy and thank you for your response.

Is there a way to get the source of iframe or its values directly? Just like if I want to automate the gathering of every info from that table. 

I mean, after fully loading of the page, those elements should appear as table, able to be located by "GetElementById" method.

I tried parsing them as xml form but failed.
Tried to parse them as innerHTMLText but also failed.

Answer (score 0):

Using a MSXML request should work. Loading only the page with the chart is probably the fastest way to get that information. It looks like you just need what appears to be the game ID `3029238` in order to generate the chart at `https://us.soccerway.com/charts/statsplus/`

```
Option Explicit

Sub Scrape_Stats()
    Dim Clip As Object: Set Clip = CreateObject("new:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim html As Object: Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    Dim Text As String

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://us.soccerway.com/charts/statsplus/3029238/", False
        .Send

        While .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        html.body.InnerHTML = .responseText
        Text = html.body.getElementsByTagName("Table")(0).outerhtml
    End With

    Clip.SetText Text
    Clip.PutInClipboard

    ws.Range("A2:H1000").ClearContents
    ws.Range("A2").Select
    ws.PasteSpecial Format:="Unicode Text"
    Set Clip = Nothing
End Sub
```